# Call a function every 1 seconds in python

Tags: python, pyglet

[image]

```
class Viewer:
   def __init__(self, width, height, arm_info, point_info, point_l):
     self.list_x = [1,2,3,4]
     self.list_y = [5,6,7,8]
     self.i = 0
     self.arm_info = arm_info
     self.point_info = point_info
  def on_key_press(self,symbol,modifiers):
     if symbol == pyglet.window.key.Z:
         self.point_info[:] = [self.list_x[self.i],self.list_y[self.i]]
         self.i += 1
```

Here to update the point_info[:] I have to press the 'Z' everytime, I just want Z to be pressed once to update point_info[:] in every 1 second .

```
 def on_key_press(self,symbol,modifiers):
     if symbol == pyglet.window.key.Z:
         for i in range(0,4):
             self.point_info[:] = [self.list_x[i],self.list_y[i]]
             time.sleep(1)
```

I have tried above but it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Here is the complete code, the render method is called from another module.

```
class Viewer(pyglet.window.Window):
def __init__(self, width, height, arm_info, point_info, point_l, mouse_in):
    self.list_x = [100,150,200,300,400]
    self.list_y = [100,150,200,300,400]
#initialisation of variables

def render(self):
    pyglet.clock.tick()
    self._update_arm()
    self.switch_to()
    self.dispatch_events()
    self.dispatch_event('on_draw')
    self.flip()

def on_draw(self):
#draws on the screen
def _update_arm(self):
#updates the coordinates of the arm , as it moves


def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
    #HERE LIES THE PROBLEM
    if symbol == pyglet.window.key.S:
        for j in range(0,4):
            self.point_info[:] = [self.list_x[j],self.list_y[j]]
            print(self.point_info)
            #below 2 lines are for drawing on the screen.
            self.clear()
            self.batch.draw()

            j=+1
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug what is happening? Try printing something before every sleep.

Comment: How exactly differs your result from your expectations? So what happens when you execute your code, and how is that different from what you expect? Consider to provide us with more context if needed (for example, the code looks like it will block the program flow, if you want other things to happen in between the time you wait for the update, you need another solution then if you can accept the blocking)

Comment: Yeah i want the point to move on the screen , (point_info contains the attribute of the point ) , the point doesnt move for 3 second at all and comes to final coordinates  [4,8] every time the loop terminates

Comment: So is this for a game or animation, where other stuff should happen in between the update steps? Like drawing?

Comment: The function is working as expected, but pyglet is only rendering after the function is finished. Is there a way to trigger a draw within the function?

Comment: The blue square is need to be moved @Decrayer

Comment: @JimWright I am not sure if its there, does it trigger the draw every time the key is pressed ?

Comment: ``time.sleep()`` **stops** the execution of your program for a given period of time. It does not call anything periodically.

Comment: I think you are missing a draw call. You only update the coordinates, but you also have to draw the object at the new position. In my below answer, I posted how you can create a continuously running program, because I think that is what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: even if i call a draw function after "self.point_info[:] = [self.list_x[self.i],self.list_y[self.i]]" , it still works the same.

Comment: I think we could need more context here. Is it possible, that you provide us with the whole code? Or a small but completely runnable example?

Comment: @Decrayer It doesn't let me post the complete code , but i have updated the question. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Sarthak Gupta: I looked into pyglet and created a small example, on how you can achieve what you want to do. Of course, you still need to adjust it for your specific case. The actual problem was caused by time.sleep(), as Psytho mentioned above. sleep() stops the program execution for the specified number of seconds. Therefore, nothing else is been called. Luckily, pyglet is offering you very convenient functions to deal with your problem and I created the below example code to show you how.

Answer (score 1):

I created a small runnable example code, on how to achieve this. The point is, that sleep() blocks the program flow. With pyglet, you have a convenient way to schedule future executions with the pyglet.clock.schedule* methods. You can use that, to call a specific function in the future.

Note: Actual, piglet is running a main loop in it's framework. If you hold the program at some position (like you do with sleep()), no further code can be executed meanwhile, therefore, no drawing can happen, if pyglet requires to call some required methods around the draw call. I guess, you are not supposed to call the on_draw() method by yourself.

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key
from pyglet import clock
import random

window = pyglet.window.Window()

label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world',
                          font_name='Times New Roman',
                          font_size=36,
                          x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')

def updatePoint(dt):
    label.x = random.random() * window.width//2
    label.y = random.random() * window.height//2

@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    if symbol == key.S:
        print('The "S" key was pressed.')
        for j in range(0,4):
            clock.schedule_once(updatePoint, j)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyglet.app.run()
```